# EF Core Navigating to 2 Properties of the Parent Class Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am running a migration on a new Class I created that has 2 objects within it that reference different objects of the same type. Here is the class

```
public class AccountOpenerWorkflowStep 
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public bool DefaultStep { get; set; }

        [Column("TrueWorkflowStepId")]
        public virtual AccountOpenerWorkflowStep TrueWorkflowStep { get; set; }

        [Column("FalseWorkflowStepId")]
        public virtual AccountOpenerWorkflowStep FalseWorkflowStep { get; set; }
    }
```

So my two properties `TrueWorkflowStep` and `FalseWorkflowStep` will point to other objects in the same table.

The issue is when I run this migration it only creates the column `FalseWorkflowStep` and not the True one.

Here is an except from the Migration

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AccountOpenerWorkflowSteps",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),
                CreatedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                ModifiedDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                Controller = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Action = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                DefaultStep = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                FalseWorkflowStepId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AccountOpenerWorkflowSteps", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AccountOpenerWorkflowSteps_AccountOpenerWorkflowSteps_False~",
                    column: x => x.FalseWorkflowStepId,
                    principalTable: "AccountOpenerWorkflowSteps",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull);
            });
```

As you can see it is only inserting the one column of the same type.

Can anyone tell me why it does not recognize both of these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Column]` attribute isn't appropriate here, because it should be applied to primitive properties, not references. EF just ignores the attributes (using different column names confirms this), falls back on its default mapping conventions --and then fails.

I happened to stumble upon [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56813276/861716) yesterday. EF's default conventions seem to have a hard time handling two uniform relationships in one class.

I didn't try your model in Npgsql, but with Sql Server EF fails likewise. The solution is to use the correct attribute:

```
[ForeignKey("TrueWorkflowStepId")]
public virtual AccountOpenerWorkflowStep TrueWorkflowStep { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("FalseWorkflowStepId")]
public virtual AccountOpenerWorkflowStep FalseWorkflowStep { get; set; }
```

Or fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountOpenerWorkflowStep>().HasOne(x => x.TrueWorkflowStep).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("TrueWorkflowStepId").IsRequired(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountOpenerWorkflowStep>().HasOne(x => x.FalseWorkflowStep).WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("FalseWorkflowStepId").IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that these are two *self* relationships, and the convention pairs them and forms one-to-one FK relationship.

Comment: @Ivan Maybe, but there are three players, the owner and the two owned steps. It's my feeling that EF's conventions need some work yet. The result is unexpected, I'd say.

Comment: I still believe the problem is that the "owner" and "referenced" are of one and the same type. I guess the process of pairing navigation properties is something like take nav property, seek the refence type for inverse nav property (collection or reference) to this type, pair them. In this case it takes `TrueWorkflowStep`, searches the target which is the same type, finds `FalseWorkflowStep`, pairs them, one-to-one relationship done :) There is no indication it shouldn't do that.

Comment: You're probably right, but I think you'll agree it isn't expected, or even correct, behaviour. It's impossible to store an `AccountOpenerWorkflowStep` with the two references pointing to two other steps. I'll try to find a related github issue or otherwise create one.

Comment: In theory you can - call the class `Node` and the two navigation properties `Prev` and `Next` and there you go - linked list in database  with `Next` being the inverse of `Prev`. CUD will be not easy, but doable (two step insert/update etc.). Anyway, this is so uncommon scenario, so I don't think EF Core team should be bothered with that - they have a lot of more important things to do as you know :) In case someone like OP  needs that, simple correct annotation or fluent config (.`HasOne(…).WithMany()` is enough) is easily resolving it. Or if the two FK properties were explicit.